# Rails 4 ajax not rendering with new data, renders blank partial or nested

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

My views are rendering and my js works but the when rendering, js doesn't render the new data on form submit

My js:

```
 $('#myform').submit(function() {  

    var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
      $(this).find('textarea').addClass('uneditable-input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        type: "POST",
    dataType: "script",
      success: function(res,json){

          alert("done!"); 
        $("#indexstream").html("<%= j render :partial => 'posts', :collection => @posts, :as => :post %>");
        alert("redenred");
        }

    }).complete(function(js){
        //act on result.
      //alert("submitted");


     $("#disabletext").removeClass('uneditable-input').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');



      $("#userlink").hide().show("slow").effect('highlight', {color: '#E5F2F7'}, 3000);



    $(function() {
  $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});




    });


    return false; // prevents normal behaviour

});

});
```

posts controller:

```
def create

    @post = Post.new(post_params) 
    @post.email = current_user.username
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    @post.firstname = current_user.firstname
    @post.lastname = current_user.lastname
    @post.avatar = current_user.avatar
    @post.school = current_user.school


    respond_to do |format| 
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path, :notice => '<i class="fa fa-check fa-5x"></i>'.html_safe }
       # format.js   # @current_item = @post 
      format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @post }

        format.js { render :partial => 'posts', :collection => @posts, :as => :post, :layout => false}

      else

        format.html { render action: 'new' }
       format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end
```

posts index.html.erb

```
<div id="indexstream">

  <%= render :partial => 'posts', :collection => @posts, :as => :post %>
          </div>
```

_posts.html.erb:

```
            <div id="streamline"> 

            <div id ="userlink">

              <%= image_tag post.avatar.url(:small), :style => "border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #e1e8ed;" %> 
           <%= post.firstname %> <%= " "  %>  <%= post.lastname %><%= " " %>  <%= link_to post.email, user_path(post.user_id), {class: "usernamelink", style: "font-weight: normal;"} %>

  <abbr class="timeago" title="<%= post.created_at.getutc.iso8601 %>" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px; font-size:90%;
                                                                             margin-top: 12px; color: #8899a6; text-decoration: none !important;">
    <%= post.created_at.to_s %>
</abbr>



            <br /><br />
              <% unless post.description == "status" %>
               <div style="background: #EF4836; width: 10px; height: 5px; float: right; margin-top: -58px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px; color: #fff; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; margin-right: 5px;">
              </div>
            <h1 style="style= z-index: 100000; color: #3399FF "><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post), {class: "usernamelink", style: "color: #3399FF;"} %></h1>


               <% if post.asset1.file? %>
            <%= image_tag post.asset1.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset2.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset2.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset3.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset3.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset4.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset4.url(:small) %>
            <% end %>
              <br /><br />
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px;"></i>  <%= post.school %>  <div style="float: right; text-align: left; margin-right: 20px;"> <i class="fa fa-usd "></i><%= post.price %></div>

              <% end %>
              <% if post.description == "status" %>
              <div style="background: #2ECC71; width: 10px; height: 5px; float: right; margin-top: -58px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px; color: #fff; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; margin-right: 5px;">

              </div>
              <h1><%= auto_link( post.title ) %></h1>


                    <% if post.asset1.file? %>
            <%= image_tag post.asset1.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset2.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset2.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset3.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset3.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset4.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset4.url(:small) %>

            <% end %>
             <br /><br />

              <% end %>






           </div>
         </div>
```

The jquery highlight effect works, but it highlights the last post that was there before the submit, it hides and unhides it. Where is the new data after I submit the form?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

posts index method:

```
 before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :js, :json, :html


    def index
    @search = Post.search do #Post.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      with(:school, current_user.school)
      paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20 
      order_by(:updated_at, :desc)  
       end
    @posts = @search.results
  end
```

**UPDATE 2 **

[image: Imgur]

controller:

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_post, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :js, :json, :html

def create

    @post = Post.new(post_params) 
    @post.email = current_user.username
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    @post.firstname = current_user.firstname
    @post.lastname = current_user.lastname
    @post.avatar = current_user.avatar
    @post.school = current_user.school


    respond_to do |format| 
      if @post.save

       puts "----------#{@posts.inspect}-------------"
       format.html { redirect_to posts_path, :notice => '<i class="fa fa-check fa-5x"></i>'.html_safe }

       format.json {render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      #format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @post }
        @posts = Post.all
        puts "----------#{@posts.count}-------------"
         format.js { render :partial => 'post', :collection => @posts, :as => :post, :layout => false }
        puts "-------------#{request.format}----------------"
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
       format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        #format.js {alert("couldn't create post")}

      end
    end

  end



def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering posts partial for collection for remote request. But in the success function of your ajax call there is a line :

```
$("#indexstream").html("<%= j render :partial => 'posts', :collection => @posts, :as => :post %>");
```

If you are putting above code in a `.js` file without `.erb`  extension you will not be able to use rails helper methods render and @posts in js.

If you are getting proper html response controller. In ajax success callback you just need to do :

```
$("#indexstream").html(res);
```

**UPDATE**

Also, For getting all posts in @posts instance after successfull creation of submitted post you can revise create action as followed.

```
def create

    #
    #
    #


    respond_to do |format| 
      if @post.save
        @posts = Post.all # This will include the @post that is saved right now.
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path, :notice => '<i class="fa fa-check fa-5x"></i>'.html_safe }
       # format.js   # @current_item = @post 
      format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @post }

        format.js { render :partial => 'posts', :collection => @posts, :as => :post, :layout => false} # This block will render partial posts for collection @posts which is set above.

      else

        format.html { render action: 'new' }
       format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end
```

Note: Don't set @posts in any before filter if you are using above code.

**UPDATE 2**

You are not setting @posts anywhere in create action please set is as :

```
...
def create

    @post = Post.new(post_params) 
    @post.email = current_user.username
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    @post.firstname = current_user.firstname
    @post.lastname = current_user.lastname
    @post.avatar = current_user.avatar
    @post.school = current_user.school


    respond_to do |format| 


      @posts = Post.all # this will set the @posts and you will get the partial render working.



      if @post.save

       puts "----------#{@posts.inspect}-------------"
       format.html { redirect_to posts_path, :notice => '<i class="fa fa-check fa-5x"></i>'.html_safe }

       format.json {render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      #format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @post }

        puts "----------#{@posts.count}-------------"
         format.js { render :partial => 'post', :collection => @posts, :as => :post, :layout => false }
        puts "-------------#{request.format}----------------"
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
       format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        #format.js {alert("couldn't create post")}

      end
    end

  end
...
```

Also in js code :

```
 $('#myform').submit(function() {  

    var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
      $(this).find('textarea').addClass('uneditable-input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        type: "POST",
    dataType: "script",
      success: function(response){
        $("#indexstream").html(response); // you might want to console the response here.
      }

    }).complete(function(js){

       //...
       //...
```

Comment: the index turns blank after doing `$("#indexstream").html(res);`it renders nothing just an empty div, is data getting lost somewhere, I just don't see it

Comment: you will not get entire page due to `format.js { render :partial => 'posts', :collection => @posts, :as => :post, :layout => false}` 
the render layout: false will only render partials for the collection @posts. You must be getting the partial posts @posts.count times in res.

Comment: ok so basically as I can see, my partial is rendering but just doesn't include the last post submitted, I'm completely lost. What do I do in the code?

Comment: relax :) I think your `@posts` instance is being set in any before filter and if this is true then your instance `@posts` is being set before your last submitted `@post` object is being created. This means that you are getting collection of posts even before storing the submitted post due to which you are not getting last submitted post.
You will have to set @posts if the submitted post gets saved successfully in the `if @post.save`.

Comment: Yes, that will make the recently created post available in @posts.

Comment: I'm using solr, gonna update my code and show you my posts index

Comment: same issue, nothing :(

Comment: `$("#indexstream").html(res);` still rendering entire page but with new data this time, rendering entire page nested in a div

Comment: can you please post the rendered output html.

Comment: ok if I have `dataType: "script" it comes up black, if I remove that, you get what is on my update2

Comment: *it comes up blank not black

Comment: check the server log of request for the type of request that is being received, is it HTML or JS. 
Post the log for request if possible. 
Also are you having any separate `_posts.js.erb` kind of file.

Comment: no but omg, there is a posts.js.coffee file, with some coffeescript from a while back that I forgot, is this relevant?

Comment: removing that file didn't make a dif

Comment: please check the server log for the type of request being received. 
I think server is receiving the HTML request. Which is rendering the whole layout.

Comment: How do I change it to JS ?

Comment: keep the dataType option of ajax request as type as 'script'. checkout(http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Also after you change dataType to 'script' you also need to inspect the format type in controllers create action as:
    `puts "-------------#{request.format}----------------"`
or by any of your preferred method.

Comment: text/javascript is the output, but now i'm just getting a blank partial, have to refresh to get everything including new data

Comment: have you updated anything from js code or controller action or partial ?

Comment: no, it's just leaving dataType in there just renders blank, without it it renders the image above

Comment: regarding the blank partial it might be the case that @posts are not having any records. so the statement:
`render :partial => 'posts', :collection => @posts, :as => :post, :layout => false` is not rendering any thing as there is no records in collection instance passed.Please check.

Comment: but `render :partial => 'posts', :collection => @posts, :as => :post, :layout => false` works fine in index.html.erb

Comment: just doesn't work in js. I'm using ...html(res) is js

Comment: just paste the output of :
`if @post.save \n puts "----------#{@posts.inspect}-------------"\n ...`
ie just before you call format.html and other formats.
In index.html.erb it is possible that you are having some records in @posts. for which the partial is rendered. In the case of js if there are no records in collection instance provided, it won't loop for rendering partial.

Comment: `puts "-------------#{request.format}----------------#{@posts.count}" `gives me nil, you are correct sir.

Comment: Looking at the list of before_action you have given there is no before filter for create action that is setting the `@posts` variable.
Since `@posts` is an class instance, it by default set to nil.Please set it to Post.all before format.js block.

Comment: ok, still not rendering the new data, just list of the posts that already exist, if I remove dataType, it will list it as in the image above with new data

Comment: can you post the current code of create action and before_action for it if any.

Comment: just post the create action related code from controller. I shall update the success function's code

Comment: I think I might have to go back to html and leave ajax behind, this is frustrating and isn't working

Comment: it does work, my mistake. js on success executes. but when I remove dataType "script" it gives me the image above

Comment: doesn't render new data